# Building Dynamic queries Postgres

Tags: sql, postgresql

I have table which stores details of each entity(employee, department). I want to build dynamic query from that table.

```
CREATE TABLE MyTable
(
    Id int primary key,
    EntityId int,
    ColumnName varchar(100),
    tablename varchar(100)
);

INSERT INTO MyTable (Id, EntityId, ColumnName, tableName)
VALUES (1,1,'name','employee');

INSERT INTO MyTable (Id, EntityId, ColumnName, tableName)
VALUES (2,1,'id','employee');

INSERT INTO MyTable (Id, EntityId, ColumnName, tableName)
VALUES (3,1,'salary','employee');

INSERT INTO MyTable (Id, EntityId, ColumnName, tableName)
VALUES (4,2,'name','departement');

INSERT INTO MyTable (Id, EntityId, ColumnName, tableName)
VALUES (5,2,'location','departement');

INSERT INTO MyTable (Id, EntityId, ColumnName, tableName)
VALUES (6,2,'id','departement');
```

Above is my table and insert scripts, How can I write a query which gives me output something like below.

```
SELECT id,name,salary from employee

SELECT id,location,name from departement
```

If i have multiple entity I should multiple select statements.

Comment: Any particular reason why you want to store it like that?

Comment: This is a known anti-pattern called EAV. Do you really want to go down that road? There are better alternatives in Postgres to do that

Comment: it sounds like a bad idea

Comment: @JakubKania I have posted a dummy schema here, but we do have similar schema.. We are storing this for doing bulk update it selects rows from multiple table requested by user.. apologies for not posting original schema for confidentiality.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If despite the discouraging comments you still want to consider this approach, here is the query that constructs one query per entity:

```
SELECT entityid,
  'SELECT ' ||
  string_agg(columnname, ', ' ORDER BY id) ||
  ' FROM ' ||
  tablename ||
  ';' AS query
FROM mytable
GROUP BY entityid, tablename;
```

Result with your example:

```
 entityid |                   query                   
----------+---------------------------------------------
        1 | SELECT name, id, salary FROM employee;
        2 | SELECT name, location, id FROM departement;
(2 rows)
```